# Custom Spring Aspect logger cause exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, spring-aop

I wrote custom realisation of system logger based on spring aop, everything was working fine But after time i started getting error like in file, which blows my head, absolutely confusing error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "scheme" is null
  at org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.getRequestURL(RequestUtil.java:51)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getRequestURL(Request.java:2455)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getRequestURL(RequestFacade.java:880)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURL(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:226)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURL(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:226)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURL(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:226)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURL(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:226)
  at com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.LoggingAspect.before(LoggingAspect.java:86)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:617)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.before(AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.java:44)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:57)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxyCglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxyCglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
  at com.example.pabp_business_logic.controller.pp.PpRSrcControllerEnhancerBySpringCGLIBca261473.getPage(<generated>)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
```

, @ToLogger annotation placed on Controllers, cause when placed on service methods it stacks transaction, even propagation don't help, and i don't why after this exception thrown it starts to retry Before method and it fills with null fields
Microservice architecture runs in k8s, mb issue in loadbalancer idk

```java
/**
 * The LoggingAspect class is an aspect that provides logging functionality for
 * annotated methods. It captures the request and response data, logs the method
 * execution details, and saves the log entity to the database.
 *
 * @author ogbozoyan
 * @date 06.04.2023
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ToLogger {
  /**
   * Specifies the action associated with the annotated method.
   * Defaults to {@link ActionEnum#UNDEFINED}.
   *
   * @return the action associated with the method
   */
  ActionEnum action() default ActionEnum.UNDEFINED;

  /**
   * Specifies the action domain associated with the annotated method.
   * Defaults to {@link ActionDomainEnum#TEST}.
   *
   * @return the action domain associated with the method
   */
  ActionDomainEnum actionDomain() default ActionDomainEnum.UNDEFINED;

  /**
   * Specifies the HTTP method associated with the annotated method.
   * Defaults to {@link HttpMethodEnum#UNDEFINED}.
   *
   * @return the HTTP method associated with the method
   */
  HttpMethodEnum httpMethod() default HttpMethodEnum.UNDEFINED;

  /**
   * Indicates whether the response should be included in the log.
   * If set to {@code true}, the response will be set in the
   * {@code responseDataAfterChange} field of the log entity.
   * Defaults to {@code false}.
   *
   * @return {@code true} if the response should be included in the log,
   * {@code false} otherwise
   */
  boolean returnResponse() default false;

  /**
   * Indicates whether the log should be saved in the database.
   * If set to {@code true}, the log entity will be saved in the database.
   * If an exception is caught in the method, the log will be saved regardless
   * of this attribute.
   * Defaults to {@code true}.
   *
   * @return {@code true} if the log should be saved in the database,
   * {@code false} otherwise
   */
  boolean isSaveInDataBase() default true;

}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_f_log", schema = "public")
public class LogEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private String userId;
  @Column(name = "user_login")
  private String userLogin;
  @Column(name = "http_method")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private HttpMethodEnum httpMethodEnum;
  @Column(name = "url")
  private String url;
  @Column(name = "action")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ActionEnum action;
  @Column(name = "action_domain")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ActionDomainEnum actionDomain;
  @Column(name = "request_data_change", columnDefinition = "varchar")
  private String requestDataChange;
  @Column(name = "response_data_after_change", columnDefinition = "varchar")
  private String responseDataAfterChange;
  @Column(name = "action_status")
  private String actionStatus;
  @Column(name = "response_status")
  private String responseStatus;
  @Column(name = "dt_create")
  private Timestamp dtCreate;
  @Column(name = "base_exception")
  private String baseException;
  @Column(name = "stack_trace_on_error")
  private String stackTraceOnError;
}
```

```java
@Component
public class CachingRequestBodyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  /**
   * Filters the servlet request and caches the request body for multiple uses.
   *
   * @param servletRequest  the servlet request
   * @param servletResponse the servlet response
   * @param chain           the filter chain
   * @throws IOException      if an I/O error occurs during the filtering process
   * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs during the
   * filtering process
   */
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    HttpServletRequest currentRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(currentRequest);

    chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class CachingResponseBodyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  /**
   * Filters the servlet request and response to cache the response body.
   *
   * @param servletRequest  the servlet request
   * @param servletResponse the servlet response
   * @param chain           the filter chain
   * @throws IOException      if an I/O error occurs during the filtering process
   * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs during the
   * filtering process
   */
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    HttpServletResponse currentResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(currentResponse);
    try {
      chain.doFilter(servletRequest, wrappedResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
    finally {
      wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
  }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface LogEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity> {
  /**
   * Saves a {@link com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity}
   * object in the database.
   *
   * <p>It is annotated with {@code @Lock} to specify the lock mode for
   * concurrent access.</p>
   *
   * @param entity the log entity to be saved
   * @return the saved log entity
   */
  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  @Override
  com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity save(com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity entity);

  /**
   * Returns a {@link Page} of entities matching the given {@link Specification}.
   *
   * @param spec     can be {@literal null}.
   * @param pageable must not be {@literal null}.
   * @return never {@literal null}.
   */
  @Override
  Page<com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity> findAll(Specification<com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity> spec, Pageable pageable);
}

  @Override
  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout = 5)
  @Retryable(retryFor = Exception.class, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
  public com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity save(com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.logger.model.LogEntity entity) {
    try {
      return repository.save(entity);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional(timeout = 200, readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public AbstractResponseDTO findAll(SearchRequest request) {
    try {
            ...
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new FilterException(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Filter exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
  @Autowired
  private HttpServletResponse httpResponse;
  @Autowired
  private LogEntityService logEntityService;
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;
  @Autowired
  private ObjectWriter objectWriter;
  private ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper;
  private ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper;
  private LogEntity logEntity;
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

  /**
   * Pointcut definition for methods annotated with @ToLogger.
   */
  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.ToLogger)")
  public void callLogger() {
  }

  /**
   * Advice executed before the annotated method execution.
   */
  /*
  In the case of a REST client making a request, the "scheme" field of the
  HttpServletRequest object should not be null. The "scheme" represents the 
  protocol scheme of the request URL, such as "http" or "https". If the "scheme" 
  is null in such cases, it could indicate a problem or misconfiguration in the
  server or the way the request is being handled.
  <p>
  Here are a few possible reasons why the "scheme" field could be null in the
  HttpServletRequest object:
  <p>
  Proxy or Load Balancer: If your application is behind a proxy or load balancer,
  it may affect how the "scheme" field is set in the HttpServletRequest object. 
  In such cases, you may need to ensure that the proxy or load balancer is properly
  configured to forward the scheme information.
  <p>
  Custom Servlet Container or Filter: If you are using a custom servlet container 
  or a filter in your application, it might modify or override the scheme value.
  Make sure your custom components handle the scheme correctly or inspect the 
  configuration to ensure it's not causing the issue.
  <p>
  RequestWrapper or HttpServletRequest Decorator: If you are using a custom 
  RequestWrapper or HttpServletRequest decorator, it's possible that the 
  implementation is not correctly propagating or setting the scheme value. Check
  your custom code to ensure it sets the scheme appropriately.
  <p>
  It's recommended to investigate your application's server configuration, 
  network setup, and any custom components involved in handling the request to 
  determine the specific cause of the "scheme" being null in the 
  HttpServletRequest object.
  */
  @Before("@annotation(com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.ToLogger)")
  public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    try {
      logEntity = new LogEntity();
      initRequest();

      ToLogger toLogger = getLogger(joinPoint);
      if (userService != null) {
        logEntity.setUserId(Optional.ofNullable(userService.getCurrentUserId()).orElse(""));
        if (logEntity.getUserId().equals("anonymous"))
          logEntity.setUserLogin(Optional.of("anonymous").orElse(""));
        else
          logEntity.setUserLogin(Optional.ofNullable(userService.getFio()).orElse(""));
      }
      logEntity.setHttpMethodEnum(toLogger.httpMethod());
      logEntity.setUrl(httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString()); //here's the cause line
      logEntity.setActionDomain(toLogger.actionDomain());
      logEntity.setAction(toLogger.action());

      RequestDataChange requestDataChange = new RequestDataChange();
      List<Params> paramsList = new ArrayList<>();

      Enumeration<String> paramNames = httpRequest.getParameterNames();
      while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = paramNames.nextElement();
        String[] values = httpRequest.getParameterValues(name);
        paramsList.add(new Params(name, values));
      }
      requestDataChange.setParams(paramsList);
      requestDataChange.setBody(getRequestBody(requestWrapper));

      logEntity.setRequestDataChange(objectWriter.writeValueAsString(requestDataChange).replaceAll(REGEX_FOR_LOGGER, ""));

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logger.debug("Error in LoggingAspect.before: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  /**
   * Advice executed after the annotated method execution.
   */
  @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.ToLogger)", returning = "returnValue")
  public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue) {
    try {
      ToLogger toLogger = getLogger(joinPoint);
      initResponse();
      ResponseDataAfterChange responseDataAfterChange = new ResponseDataAfterChange();

      if (toLogger.returnResponse()) {
        responseDataAfterChange.setBody(getResponseBody(returnValue));
      }

      logEntity.setResponseDataAfterChange(objectWriter.writeValueAsString(responseDataAfterChange).replaceAll(REGEX_FOR_LOGGER, ""));

      logEntity.setResponseStatus(String.valueOf(httpResponse != null ? httpResponse.getStatus() : 0));
      logEntity.setActionStatus(String.valueOf(ActionStatusEnum.SUCCESSFULLY));
      logEntity.setDtCreate(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));

      if (toLogger.isSaveInDataBase()) {
        logEntityService.save(logEntity);
      }
      logger.info(logEntity.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logger.debug("Error in LoggingAspect.afterReturning: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  /**
   * Advice executed after the annotated method throws an exception.
   */
  @AfterThrowing(value = "@annotation(com.example.pabp_business_logic.aspect.ToLogger)", throwing = "exception")
  public void afterError(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable exception) {
    try {
      ToLogger toLogger = getLogger(joinPoint);

      logEntity.setResponseDataAfterChange(null);
      logEntity.setResponseStatus(String.valueOf(500));
      logEntity.setActionStatus(String.valueOf(ActionStatusEnum.ERROR));
      logEntity.setBaseException(exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
      logEntity.setStackTraceOnError(ExceptionUtils.getMessage(exception));
      logEntity.setDtCreate(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));

      logEntityService.save(logEntity);
      logger.info(logEntity.toString());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logger.debug("Error in LoggingAspect.afterError: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the request body from the given request wrapper.
   */
  private String getRequestBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {
    try {
      String bodyRequest = new String(request.getContentAsByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      bodyRequest = bodyRequest.replaceAll(REGEX_FOR_LOGGER, "");
      return bodyRequest;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the response body from the given response object.
   */
  private String getResponseBody(Object response) {
    try {
      if (response == null)
        return null;
      return response.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initializes the current request.
   */
  private void initRequest() {
    this.httpRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) Objects.requireNonNull(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())).getRequest();
    this.requestWrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) httpRequest;
    logger.debug("Init Request httpRequest: " + httpRequest + " " + "requestWrapper: " + requestWrapper);
  }

  /**
   * Initializes the current request.
   */
  private void initResponse() {
    this.httpResponse = ((ServletRequestAttributes) Objects.requireNonNull(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())).getResponse();
    this.responseWrapper = (ContentCachingResponseWrapper) httpResponse;
    logger.debug("Init Response httpResponse: " + httpResponse + " " + "responseWrapper: " + responseWrapper);
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the @ToLogger annotation from the given join point.
   */
  private ToLogger getLogger(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    /*================Extract information from the annotation===============*/
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    return signature.getMethod().getAnnotation(ToLogger.class);
    /*=====================================================================*/
  }
}
```

Expected work correctly idk

Comment: Welcome to SO. While it is commendable to try and post a minimal reproducer here, your code does not represent one: (1) Nobody wants to copy & paste 6 classes and guess about dozens of commits, some of which have multiple suggestions in my IDE. (2) Still, several classes, package names in the sample classes, Spring configuration and a little driver application are missing, i.e. nobody can reproduce the problem. So please, push a complete, minimal reproducer to GitHub. Then I can certainly take a look. Just parsing the code in my head does not help.

Comment: BTW, did you read the comment about scheme in the aspect code? Did you write that aspect or did someone else? If someone else, can you ask the author about it? Something like `git annotate` or the corresponding IDE feature can show you who committed that comment.

Comment: That logger was my work task to invent logger for our system
I'm left that comment with my suspicions about the source of the error
Here's https://github.com/ogbozoyan/stack-overflow-logger
Thank you for your response, i already spent 2 weeks for this issue

Comment: Can you please update the project, so that I can actually run the application without setting up Docker or a database server? I get the error: `APPLICATION FAILED TO START ... Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class. Consider the following: If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.`

Comment: Updated, added H2 and Swagger for  simplicity

Comment: OK, and what other than issuing `GET http://localhost:8888/example` in an HTTP client do I need to do after application start-up in order to reproduce the error? It seems to work fine here.

Comment: That's all what you need to do, i didn't change anything, but when i run application on container and communicate with him it gives this error. If I knew what it was about, I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Well, the whole purpose of the GitHub project was to reproduce the problem. For me, it works fine, but I am running it locally, not in a container. I am also not sure, if the problem for you happens sporadically or is always reproducible for each call when running inside the container. In the latter case, I would think that it is a container configuration problem, not a problem about Spring or AOP proxies in general.

Comment: I solve this problem. So in UserService was method which does call to other service and idk what happens it sets null HttpServletResponse object :D 
Removed that now works more better

Comment: Then please, write a comprehensive answer for the benefit of this community here, which in a few days you can also mark as accepted. Otherwise, this question will be listed as unanswered forever. BTW, a small correction: Your `HttpServletResponse` is not null like you said, only its `scheme` field. The error message in your stack trace proves that.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. So in UserService was method which does call to other service and idk what happens it sets null HttpServletResponse object :D Removed that now works more better

Comment: This answer is not helpful. It is incorrect, too, see my previous comment above. Please give your own posts some more love and think about how to make them helpful to other community members. It is give and take here on SO. What exactly did you change, and how did it solve the problem. Where is the code? Thank you.

Comment: i can't share UserService code part, but i can tell what was there:
logEntity.setUserLogin(Optional.ofNullable(userService.getFio()).orElse(""));
In userservice.getFio() was Retrofit request to other service and i was pooling while don't get answer from that service, i just refactored that method, moved logic from another service to my and that's it 
Maybe issue was in pooling who knows

Comment: Please learn how to ask and how to answer questions. That you cannot share code is - with all due respect - a lame excuse. Nobody needs your classified original code, just enough to understand the problem and its solution. Feel free to anonymise code, rename stuff, whatever. Please also move the code from your comment into your answer (there is an edit button), format it properly and explain a bit more. This answer is too sloppy. Sorry to be so blunt, I mean to guide you towards writing better answers here. Answers like this will only attract downvotes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).